# How to get week formatted string in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query (sql server 2008):

```
SELECT sum(data.freq) as freq,data.week as week FROM (
SELECT 
count(daterequested) as freq,
datepart(wk,daterequested) as week,
daterequested 
FROM request ma
JOIN contracts mc ON (mc.uid= ma.uid)
JOIN groups og ON og.groupuid = mc.groupuid
JOIN member m ON (m.memberuid = mc.memberuid)
WHERE daterequested BETWEEN 
DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())
AND
GETDATE()
AND isdeleted = 0
GROUP BY datepart(wk,daterequested),daterequested
--ORDER BY daterequested ASC
) data
GROUP BY data.week
```

The result is a table with the following data:

[image]

Instead of showing the **week number** I would like to show the week formatted as following:

`MM/dd` where MM = month and dd is the day where the week starts.

It would be great if I can format starting with first day of the week, then a middle slash, then the last day of that week and finally the month: example: 11-17/04 (April 11 to 17), etc.

Here is the final table that I would like to get:

[image]

Any clue?

Comment: be careful since datapart (wk ,adate) returns the week of the year,  your group by may not return the expected result when you have multiple-year data.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs it just found a solution, maybe is not the best but works.

```
SELECT sum(data.freq) as freq,
data.week as week, CAST(data.weekstart as varchar) + '-' + CAST(data.weekend as varchar) + '/' + CAST(data.monthend as varchar) as formatweek
FROM (
SELECT 
count(daterequested) as freq,
datepart(wk,daterequested) as week,
DATEPART(dd,DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, daterequested)-1), daterequested)) weekstart,
DATEPART(dd,DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, daterequested)), daterequested)) weekend,
DATEPART(mm,DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, daterequested)), daterequested)) monthend,
daterequested 
FROM requestma
JOIN contracts mc ON (mc.uid= ma.uid)
JOIN groups og ON og.groupuid = mc.groupuid
JOIN member m ON (m.memberuid = mc.memberuid)
WHERE daterequested BETWEEN 
DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())
AND
GETDATE()
AND isdeleted = 0
GROUP BY datepart(wk,daterequested),daterequested
--ORDER BY daterequested ASC
) data
GROUP BY data.week,data.weekstart,data.weekend,data.monthend
```